# Mysql Update combined with inner join and not excist

Tags: mysql

after some struggle I finally have a working code to query the database and get the results that I want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t1 INNER JOIN email_list_subscribers ON email_list_subscribers.subscriberid=t1.subscriberid
WHERE lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
      AND t1.listid = 206
      AND eventtype = 'Sent an Email Campaign'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t2
                      WHERE t1.subscriberid = t2.subscriberid 
                            AND t2.lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
                            AND t2.eventtype IN ('Opened an Email Campaign', 'Clicked on a link'))
GROUP BY `email_list_subscribers`.`subscriberid`
```

Now I'm in a new struggle to update the email_list_subscribers.confirmed from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.

I have tried several UPDATE structures, but none of them will parse.

Thank you for your time and minds.

Update:

My ruthlessly failed attempts

```
UPDATE epaper_list_subscribers
SET confirmed = 1
FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t1 INNER JOIN email_list_subscribers ON email_list_subscribers.subscriberid=t1.subscriberid
WHERE lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
      AND t1.listid = 206
      AND eventtype = 'Sent an Email Campaign'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t2
                      WHERE t1.subscriberid = t2.subscriberid 
                            AND t2.lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
                            AND t2.eventtype IN ('Opened an Email Campaign', 'Clicked on a link'))
```

And

```
SELECT * 
FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t1 INNER JOIN email_list_subscribers ON email_list_subscribers.subscriberid=t1.subscriberid
WHERE lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
      AND t1.listid = 206
      AND eventtype = 'Sent an Email Campaign'
      AND NOT EXISTS (UPDATE email_list_subscribers
                      SET email_list_subscribers.confirmed = 1
                      FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t2
                      WHERE t1.subscriberid = t2.subscriberid 
                            AND t2.lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
                            AND t2.eventtype IN ('Opened an Email Campaign', 'Clicked on a link'))
```

Since FROM is not possible in an UPDATE, is it maybe possible to output the results of the select query to a TEMP TABLE and do the update on that?

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee99

Comment: Where is your update statement? We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: Sorry, it's Friday...

Comment: There are no `From` and `Group By` clauses for the `Update` statement.

Comment: Ok forget about the GROUP BY, but the from I will need to make these connections. 
Is their another way to do this.

Comment: The `confirmed` column is in how many tables?

Comment: Only in the subscribers one, hence I need the join :(

Comment: can you post your table definitions and some sample rows here or sqlfiddle? your update query has syntax error.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee99

Comment: Answered on another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162143/mysql-update-table-depending-on-not-exist-from-other-table

Answer (score 0):

P.S: I have not tested this code. Also, verify that the columns are associated to the proper tables.

```
UPDATE epaper_list_subscribers
SET confirmed = 1
WHERE email_list_subscribers.subscriberid=epaper_list_subscribers.subscriberid 
      AND email_list_subscribers.lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
      AND email_list_subscriber_events.listid = 206
      AND email_list_subscribers.eventtype = 'Sent an Email Campaign'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM email_list_subscriber_events AS t2
                      WHERE t1.subscriberid = t2.subscriberid 
                            AND t2.lastupdate BETWEEN 0 AND 9999999999 
                            AND t2.eventtype IN ('Opened an Email Campaign', 'Clicked on a link'))
```

Comment: Cannot get this working in any way. 

WHERE email_list_subscribers.subscriberid=t1.subscriberid 

Is already mega weird since t1 has not been declared yet. But thanks for trying!

Comment: Oh yeah. Replace `t1` with `epaper_list_subscribers`. I forgot to update that.

Comment: Hmm, I get the following error:
" #1054 - Unknown column 'epaper_list_subscriber_events.lastupdate' in 'where clause' "  (btw I changed all the words "email" into "epaper". (my live server and local one use different table pretext)